# Backgroundwork DoWork process not running after installing application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, installshield

I have an application which is installed using installshield. The application works fine during debugging and when publishing using VS but when I run the installed version, the DoWork process doesn't get hit and I can seem to determine why.

I have added the code below, as you can see I have added code to write to a text file for debugging.

The entry "Line:278" is logged straight before "Line:281". The problem is that the DoWork should run inbetween those and log entries for those lines of code. This all works fine during debugging.

It is obvious from these logs that the DoWork (which contains the main code) is never hit when running the installed version.

```
   private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            File.AppendAllText("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\errorloghardware.txt", "Line:278" + Environment.NewLine);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(txtTerminal.Text);
            File.AppendAllText("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\errorloghardware.txt", "Line:281" + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        }

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(txtTerminal.Text);
            File.AppendAllText("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\errorloghardware.txt","Line:292" + Environment.NewLine);
        }
```

The DoWork process includes an entry to log the line number on it's first row, so I didn't think there would be much point posting the lengthy method here.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have an exception in your background worker DoWork. Check the `e.Error` property in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler.

Comment: But from looking at the log, it appears that line 1 of that method isn't hit so how would I get an exception before any of the code is run?

Comment: Logging the line itself could give an exception. Try to log the error to see if that's not the case.

Comment: Do you know how I can catch the exception? There seems to be no Error property in e. I tried to add a try catch to log the error but that also achieves nothing.

Comment: if line no 278 is not printed ,that means work is not completed.
or itself is giving exception which will not show up in installed version. try to catch it and print it in some temperary richbox

Comment: The property can be found in the `backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted` eventargs.

Comment: @Charlie 278 and 281 are both printed.

Comment: @codemonkey I have tried this now and still nothing. The log just contains this, which goes on forever:
Line:278
Line:281
Line:278
Line:281
Line:278
Line:281
Line:278
Line:281
Line:278
Line:281
Line:278
Line:281
Line:278
Line:281
Line:278
Line:281
Line:278
Line:281
Line:278
Line:281
Line:278
Line:281
Line:278
Line:281

Comment: Are you sure the DoWork method gets executed? Check the event registration to be sure. Or throw an error in there and log the error in the `backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted` handler.

Comment: @codemonkey No, it definitely does not get executed, that is the problem, the code is never touched. Why does this problem only occur in the installed version?

Comment: @codemonkey I have finally managed to get it to show an error, the error is pasted below but I am unable to see where the file is missing from: ErrorLine288: Could not load file or assembly 'ApplicationJoin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Deploy the ApplicationJoin dll alongside your application (same folder). You can also put the 'Copy Local' property of the reference in your project to 'true', that will copy the dll to the bin folder when you compile your application.

Comment: @codemonkey I think the issue is that there is no DLL generated for applicationjoin, so currently I am referencing the .exe Is there a reason why it wouldn't generate a DLL, even after publish?

Comment: There's no problem with referencing an exe file, as long as you deploy the exe with your application. (exe's are just fancy dll's)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really have hard coded directory references?  You should be doing something like this instead:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop))
```

It's not really relevant that you used InstallShield to create an installer.  What's relevant is you need to understand the exact dependencies of your application and handle this in your deployment logic.  If you have a dependency on a DLL, make sure you deploy it.

In this scenario it's inappropriate to assume that a certain folder would exist and that the logged on user would have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that will be approach to find the error .Otherwise work is not completed yet

```
  private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
    if (e.Error == null)
        { 
           richBox1.Text=ex.Message;

      }else{
          try{
        File.AppendAllText("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\errorloghardware.txt", "Line:278" + Environment.NewLine);
        reset_all_variables()
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(txtTerminal.Text);
        File.AppendAllText("C:\\Users\\Jamie\\Desktop\\errorloghardware.txt", "Line:281" + Environment.NewLine);        

          }catch (Exception ex)
         {
           richBox1.Text=ex.Message;
         }
}
```

Comment: I thought exception might be about printing in File so i used richbox

Comment: I think you meant e.Error.Message but I am just trying your answer now.

Comment: Reset all values ,I don't have any other reason ,that might be causing the problem :(

Comment: Why do you create a new backgroundworker in the RunWorkerCompleted? The new backgroundworker has no events registered too. (No Do_Work registered) This code looks very strange!!

Comment: @codemonkey I tried it without the new backgroundwork and it's the same thing. My DoWork actually has a time delay inside it of 5 seconds and I can see those two lines I previously mentioned are being logged roughly every second so I know that the DoWork is simply not being touched.

Comment: Yes My mistake,even Progress Changed will be called after Work_Completed_Event.

Answer (score 0):

Use mutex to synchronize the access to file. Probably the file is busy from main task when you are trying to write from background task. Or simply define global `Stream` object and keep it open.